# Meaning of 情状酌量以前 in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, sentence

> 『……いや。というか敵。何であろうと敵。　悪いけど情状酌量以前に敵……！

I know what 情状酌量 is but how the 以前 changes it in this sentence?
My personal translation therefore poor is something like: "Sorry but hostility/make a enemy in 情状酌量以前"

For more context:

> ……その人物に責任はないにせよ、彼女にだって、学校側の仕事を押しつけられる責任も義理もないのである。　せめて、なんというか。もうちょっと空気を読んで平日にやってきてくれたのなら、と愚痴の一つも言いたくなる。